# The function lda() throws an error when passing a subset argument

Tags: r

This error looks common but I've can't seem to get my head round this.

I've been given the following code (on a course but it's (the code) not graded) as a shortcut to doing LDA. Apparently it works on some computers but not mine. I've upgraded R and R studio and also the MASS library. Any ideas?

The error I get is:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'training' not found
```

The code is

```
lda.valid <- function(formula,data,...,train.fraction=0.75){
    grouping <- model.response(model.frame(formula,data))
    tbl <- table(grouping,lda(formula,data,...,CV=TRUE)$class)
    CV <- sum(diag(tbl))/sum(tbl)
    n <- nrow(data)
    training <- sample(1:n,n*train.fraction)
    lda.training <- lda(formula,data,...,subset=training)
    lda.pred <- predict(lda.training,data[-training,])
    tbl <- table(grouping[-training],lda.pred$class)
    VAL <- sum(diag(tbl))/sum(tbl)
    c(CV=CV,VAL=VAL)
}
```

I run the following and get the error. Is it related to the "..." (ellipsis)

```
lda.valid(Species~.,data=iris,prior=c(1/3,1/3,1/3),train.fraction=0.5)
```

I was looking at the `trycatch` stuff to catch the error but don't see how I can print the stacktrace.

Any hints or suggestions. I probably don't understand the stacktrace at this point.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thanks for posting a clear question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs where you call `lda.training <- lda(...)`. This seems to be related to internals of the `lda()` function, and it's not clear to me why this happens.

However, the intent of this code seems to perform the lda using a only a training subset of the data.

This is easy enough to specify directly by subsetting the data in advance. So I suggest replacing the offending line with

```
lda.training <- lda(formula, data[training, ], ...)
```

Thus the complete function is:

```
library(MASS)

lda.valid <- function(formula, data, ..., train.fraction = 0.75){
  grouping <- model.response(model.frame(formula, data))
  tbl <- table(grouping, lda(formula, data, ..., CV = TRUE)$class)
  CV <- sum(diag(tbl))/sum(tbl)
  n <- nrow(data)
  training <- sample(1:n, n*train.fraction)
  lda.training <- lda(formula, data[training, ], ...)  # <<<--- Changed
  lda.pred <- predict(lda.training, data[-training, ])
  tbl <- table(grouping[-training], lda.pred$class)
  VAL <- sum(diag(tbl))/sum(tbl)
  c(CV = CV, VAL = VAL)
}

lda.valid(Species~., data = iris, prior = c(1/3, 1/3, 1/3), train.fraction = 0.5)
```

This results in:

```
> lda.valid(Species~., data = iris, prior = c(1/3, 1/3, 1/3), train.fraction = 0.5)
  CV  VAL 
0.98 0.96
```